# Multiple .php process that never closes

Tags: php

I have this `ajax.ads.php` script that i include from another file, and then executes without any problem and does it job, but when it finishes it never terminates the process and every time it executes opens a new instance, and there are a lot of them doing nothing, and it builds up and consumes CPU Time, and i can't close them.

I have tried setting a max execution time of 5 seconds `ini_set('max_execution_time',5);` and `exit();` but does nothing.

What can i do?

```
<?
ini_set('max_execution_time',5);
$pagina_actual="inicio";
$categoria_actual="inicio";
require_once("panel/includes/config.php");
require_once("panel/includes/funciones.php");

$viewport_escritorio=768;

if (!isset($_SESSION["publicidades_mostradas"])){
    $_SESSION["publicidades_mostradas"]="0";
}

$fecha=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$tipo=($_GET["tipo"]);
$pagina=$_GET["pagina"];
$viewport=$_GET["viewport"];
$orden="";
if (isset($_GET["orden"])){
    $orden=$_GET["orden"];
}

$filtro_publicidades="
        AND p.fecha_inicio <= '".date('Y-m-d')."' 
        AND p.fecha_fin >= '".date('Y-m-d')."'
        AND rpp.pagina = '".$pagina."'
        
        ";

$a=explode("(", $tipo);
if (isset($a[1]) && end($a)=="rotador)"){
    //si es rotador
    $filtro_repetidas="AND p.id NOT IN (".$_SESSION["publicidades_mostradas"].")";
    $orden_query="ORDER BY p.fecha_ultima_visualizacion";
} else {
    $filtro_repetidas="";
    $orden_query="ORDER BY rpp.orden, rpp.id";
}

if ($tipo=="pie de pagina (rotador)"){
    $filtro_repetidas="";
}

$result=$mysqli->query("
            SELECT p.id, p.nombre, p.foto_escritorio, p.foto_celular, p.link, 
                    p.tipo_link, p.visualizaciones, p.youtube
            FROM publicidad p
                LEFT JOIN renglon_publicidad_pagina rpp ON rpp.id_publicidad=p.id
            WHERE p.tipo='".$tipo."'
            AND p.estado='activo'
            $filtro_publicidades
            $filtro_repetidas
            $orden_query
            LIMIT 1
            OFFSET $orden ");
$item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (isset($_GET["debug"])){
    echo "
        SELECT p.id, p.nombre, p.foto_escritorio, p.foto_celular, p.link, p.tipo_link, p.visualizaciones, p.youtube
        FROM publicidad p
        LEFT JOIN renglon_publicidad_pagina rpp ON rpp.id_publicidad=p.id
        WHERE p.tipo='".$tipo."'
        AND p.estado='activo'
        $filtro_publicidades
        $filtro_repetidas
        $orden_query
        LIMIT 1
        OFFSET $orden ";
}

if ($item["id"]!=""){

    $result=$mysqli->query("
            UPDATE publicidad SET
            fecha_ultima_visualizacion=NOW(),
            visualizaciones='".($item["visualizaciones"]+1)."'
            WHERE id='".$item["id"]."'");

    $_SESSION["publicidades_mostradas"].=",".$item["id"];

    if ($item["link"]!="" || $item["youtube"]!=""){
?>
    <a href="<?=$item["link"]?>" data-id="<?=$item["id"]?>" <?=$item["tipo_link"]=="externo"?"target='_blank'":""?> <?=$item["youtube"]!=""?'data-youtube="'.solo_codigo_youtube($item["youtube"]).'"':""?> <?=$item["youtube"]!=""?'data-youtube="'.solo_codigo_youtube($item["youtube"]).'"':""?>>
<? 
    }
?>
<? 
    if ($item["nombre"]!=""){
?>
<? 
        if ($viewport>$viewport_escritorio){
?>
            <img src="<?='contenido/'.$carpeta_publicidades_original.$item["foto_escritorio"]?>" border="0" class="img-responsive center-block hidden-xs">
<? 
        } else {
?>        
            <img src="<?='contenido/'.$carpeta_publicidades_thumb.$item["foto_celular"]?>" border="0" class="img-responsive center-block hidden-lg hidden-sm hidden-md center-block">
<? 
        }
?>    
<? 
    }
?>

<? 
    if ($item["link"]!="" || $item["youtube"]!=""){
?>
        </a>
<? 
    }
?>

<? 
}
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Please show us `ajax.ads.php` otherwise we will just have to make a few guesses

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the 
[Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Where do you do a `session_start()`

Comment: on the config.php file